# showing non-existence of a retraction $r: B^2 \rightarrow S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have been asked to show that there is no retraction $r: B^2 \rightarrow S^1$ where $B^2$ is the unit ball.   I looked up the definitions of retraction and it looks like given  $A\subset C$, $r: X \rightarrow A$ is a retraction if $r(a) = a $ for each $a \in A$.

I have thought a bit about this but I am not sure how to do it. I certainly can't think of a retraction from the definition.

How to do this? Do I need to say something about inclusions? How do I argue this?

I am using Munkres topology text.

Comment: If such a retraction existed then it would satisfy $r\circ i=id_{S^1}$ where $i:S^1\to B^2$ is the inclusion. Use this to show there is an injective homomorphism $i_*:\pi_1(S^1, b_0)\to\pi_1(B^2, b_0)$ where $b_0=(1,0)$. But if you know what are the fundamental groups of these spaces, you know such a homomorphism cannot exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively you will need to tear the disk to do it.  So it can't be done continuously.

More precisely, if there's a retraction, it would induce an injective map on the fundamental groups.

But of course $\pi_1(S^1)\cong\Bbb Z,$ whereas $\pi_1(B^2)=0.$

So there's no injective map from $\pi_1(S^1)$ to $\pi_1(B^2).$

Comment: It its not true that they will have the same homotopy type if there is a retraction. For example, there is a retraction from $S^1 \vee S^1$ to $S^1$ but clearly, they don't have the same homotopy type. What is true, is that the map induced on $\pi_1$ by inclusion of a retract is injective. So if there were a retraction $D^2 \to S^1$, then the map induced on $\pi_1$ by $S^1 \hookrightarrow D^2$ would have been injective, which is obviously not possible.

Comment: Alright,  I probably would need an absolute neighborhood retract or some such.  I should have been more careful.    @feynhat